# Both my NodeMCU and my ESP01 turn off after a few minutes

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266

I am trying to make a simple hardware to turn off and on a lamp in my room remotely using a database I have. For this i wanted to use ESP8266 in the ESP-01 board.

For workbench testing I have a 2 amps 5v source. I used a 3.3V regulator (LD33V) to turn the ESP-01 on and managed to make a connection with a database where I have the "on/off flag". Works like a charm with a LED and a 330 ohms resistor.

Thing is after a few moments (I have not measured, but only a few minutes), the board turns off completely. I realised it could be an excessive current drain, so I uploaded the same code to a NodeMCU board and powered it with a cellphone charger, turning on and off the in-board LED. The same happened.

I am guessing it can be a software issue, because it doesn't seem to be hardware after these tests. Maybe I need to set any virtual flag, or something.

The ESP-01 has the following in the pins:
VCC: 3.3V from the regulator
GND: 0V from the regulator
GPI02: 330 ohms resistor and the LED
GPIO0: floating (yes, I do ground it when programming)
TX / RX: floating
RST: Vcc
CH_PD (enable): Vcc

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

#define led 2 //pin of the external led

// Inicialização do WiFi
const char* ssid = "xxxxxx";
const char* pass = "xxxxxx";
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; // made-up MAC

WiFiClient client;

// Inicialização do MySQL
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);
// Create an instance of the cursor passing in the connection
MySQL_Cursor cur = MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
IPAddress server_addr(XXX, XXX , XXX, XXX);          // MySQL server IP
char user[] = "xxxxxx";           // MySQL user
char password[] = "xxxxxx";       // MySQL password
char BANCODEDADOS[] = "USE xxxxxx";

void toggle_lamp(void){

  // FAZ UM SELECT SIMPLES
  char query[] = "SELECT STATUS FROM devices WHERE ID = 1";
  MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
  cur_mem->execute(query);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Executando query: ");
  Serial.println(query);

  // Fetch the columns (required) but we don't use them.
  column_names *columns = cur_mem->get_columns();

  // Read the row (we are only expecting the one)
  row_values *row = NULL;
  //char* result = NULL;
  int lamp_status;

  do {
    row = cur_mem->get_next_row();
    if (row != NULL) {
     // result = row->values[0];
     lamp_status = atoi(row->values[0]);

    }
  } while (row != NULL);

  // Deleting the cursor also frees up memory used
  delete cur_mem;

  // USA O RESULTADO PARA ACENDER UM LED
  //int lamp_status = atoi(result);
  //Serial.println(result);
  Serial.println(lamp_status);
  if(lamp_status == 1){
    digitalWrite(led,HIGH); 
  }
  else{
    lamp_status = 0;
    digitalWrite(led,LOW);

  }

}

void setup(void){

  // Define a saída como output
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);

  // Inicializa a porta Serial
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");

  // Inicializa a conexão WiFi
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // REALIZA A CONEXÃO COM O MYSQL
  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)) 
   {
      delay(1000);

      // Initiate the query class instance
      MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
      cur_mem->execute(BANCODEDADOS);

      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("Conectado ao MySQL");
      Serial.print("Usuario:");
      Serial.println(user);
   }
   else
   {
      Serial.println("A conexão falhou");
      conn.close();
   }

} // end setup()

void loop(void){

  toggle_lamp();
  delay(1250);

}
```

Comment: It's possible that it's a software problem rather than power.

Have you tried monitoring the serial output when this happens? You may need to set the serial speed on your terminal program to 74880 - that's the speed that the boot loader will output exception and booting information. If you haven't tried monitoring the serial output, I'd temporarily change the program to use 74880 instead of 115200 (just so you can see its debugging output as well as the boot loader output) and run a terminal program with it to see if it shows you anything interesting.

Comment: To get it I tried using the ESP plugged to the PC (and powered by it as well), but I couldn't get the error to happen. Also, to see if there was a big current drain, I tried letting it ON powered by the supply and the regulator without powering the LED. The error happened

Comment: Have you tried connecting a large (say, 470µF electrolytic but the exact value doesn't matter a lot) capacitor between 3.3V and GND on the ESP? That might stabilize power enough for when it's not getting power from the PC. (just in case you're not used to them, electrolytic capacitors are polarized, so if you use one make sure the NEGATIVE terminal goes to GND)

Comment: Hey John, Thanks for the help. I found the issue, it was a defective capacitor on the power source, but there was also a bug on the code. Since it never actually closed the MySQL connection, sometimes the connection would fall and it couldn't restablish because this was not on the loop. I added a function to start the connection every loop and close it after the queries.